# I need help making an animated full screen button for my website using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm working on an animated button for my website that transforms an icon like [this](https://www.svgrepo.com/show/361483/enter-full-screen.svg) into one like [this](https://www.svgrepo.com/show/521684/full-screen-exit.svg) and back. The goal is for a spam-proof transition to smoothly take place between the two states in a style similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qtna8bz3/) one I made earlier.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function toggleState(target) {
  target.classList.toggle("animate");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --btn-size: min(8vh, 8vw);
  --bar-dimen: calc(var(--btn-size) * 0.225);
  --bar-thick: calc(var(--bar-dimen) * 0.5);
  --animation: 0.50s;
  --anim-half: calc(var(--animation) / 2);
  --anim-func: ease-in-out;
  --btn-color: black;
}

body {
  margin: 1%;
}

#fullscreen-btn {
  height: var(--btn-size);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func);
}

#fullscreen-btn::before,
#fullscreen-btn::after,
#fullscreen-btn span::before,
#fullscreen-btn span::after {
  height: var(--bar-dimen);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border: var(--bar-thick) none var(--btn-color);
  transition: rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func);
}

#fullscreen-btn::before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid none none solid;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#fullscreen-btn::after {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid solid none none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#fullscreen-btn span::before {
  content: "";
  border-style: none none solid solid;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#fullscreen-btn span::after {
  content: "";
  border-style: none solid solid none;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#fullscreen-btn.animate {
  rotate: 360deg;
}

#fullscreen-btn.animate::before,
#fullscreen-btn.animate::after,
#fullscreen-btn.animate span::before,
#fullscreen-btn.animate span::after {
  transition: rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func);
  rotate: 180deg;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullscreen-btn" onclick="toggleState(this)">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

First, is there any way for me to remove the `<span>` from the `<div>`? Second, is there anything I can do to optimize my code, make it nicer, neater, etc.? And finally, does anyone have any ideas to make the animation nicer, more confined inside of the `<div>` while animating, and more on-par with the menu button?